# Why isn't my window insulation film shrinking with heat from my blow dryer?

Tags: insulation, plastic

I have cleaned my window and frame. I have applied the double sided tape and peeled off the top cover. I put the plastic on and pressed down all the sides. The window insulation plastic is not shrinking. Could it be that my blow dryer isn't hot enough?

Answer (score 3):

My wife and I installed window film on our home for many years, using several brands. We never found the heat from a common hair dryer inadequate. Some possible reasons for your trouble:

- The film needs to be reasonably well fit to begin with. You'll have a hard time removing major slack without shrinking the entire sheet. If done well you really only need to shrink a small zone around a few sides. The tension then tightens the entire window, though you may need to touch up any loose spots.
- Your tape may be releasing. Ideally the tape is applied on plane with the film, or around an outside corner. If it's on an *inside*-facing surface it'll likely pull free.
- You simply aren't applying enough heat. As Armand suggested in a comment, do some experimenting on scrap. When you heat the film to a certain point it shrinks very quickly. It's obvious when that happens. If it's not happening, move closer. Always keep moving, but pass repeatedly over an area until it shrinks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you buy the indoor variety. It's not always easy to tell the difference. Happened to me a month ago

Comment: Is this intended as an answer to the question? Why wouldn't the outdoor type shrink as expected, should it be used indoors? More information or reasoning would improve your post. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].